# Distuils: Create script which does not "block" console when starting wx application

Tags: python, wxpython, distutils

In my `setup.py` I have defined an entry point like this:

```
entry_points={
      'console_scripts' : [
            'cofo = cofo:gui_main'
      ]
},
```

Calling `python setup.py develop` generates the `cofo` script as expected. But `gui_main` starts a wxWindows application and I would like to "free" the console afterwards. How can I do that? If I use `gui_scripts` instead of `console_scripts` it does not make a difference.

**Update:**

With "free" the console, I mean that I would like to start the script from the command prompt (i.e. passing command line arguments to it), but would like to have the command prompt available after the gui has started. Something like this:

```
Last login: Mon Oct  8 15:34:28 on ttys002
localhost:~ domma$ cofo some arguments
... gui starts and after that ...
localhost:~ domma$
```

At the moment I don't get a waiting prompt, because the script is running and "blocking" the command line. My primary plattform is OS X, but I would be interested in a general solution.

Comment: Note that it is unusual for GUI applications (under Linux, at least) not to block the console they're invoked from. Better use `yourscript.py &` or a wrapper scrip if you find it uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With linux/unix (including Mac OS X) shells, you can run a command, and tell it to go to the background by suffixing it with "&". eg:

```
$ cofo some arguments &
```

Here is a page with some extra info on this: http://www.bsdguides.org/guides/netbsd/beginners/job_control/print

I would recommend just manaully using that/educating your users to use that (if they are already using the a cli, then that is not alot extra to ask.) If you really want your command to go the the background by default, you can wrap your script with a small bash script that uses the above mentioned method.

Comment: I could not manage to get the `os.fork` solutions to work. Because distutils cannot install bash scripts, I had to use another python scripts. But using `subprocesss` is could start a new job in the background, which gives the behaviour is wanted to have. Therefor I'll accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal example works for me using Windows 7 32 bit, Python 2.7.1, wx 2.8.12.2 (msw-unicode).  When `python setup.py develop` is invoked, both `cofo.exe` and `cofogui.exe` are generated for the console and GUI scripts respectively.

When `cofogui.exe` is executed, no console window appears (Is this what you mean by "free" console?)

This example is using the [setuptools](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html) enhancements to `distutils`.

```
setup.py:

#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='cofo',
      packages=['cofo'],
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts' : [
              'cofo = cofo:gui_main'
              ],
          'gui_scripts' : [
              'cofogui = cofo:gui_main'
              ]
          }
      )
```

and

```
cofo/__init__.py:

#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

def gui_main():
    app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
    frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Update:**
Windows and Unix based platforms operate differently when starting processes.  On Unix systems, if the application is to remain running in the background the usual process is to use the `os.fork()` system call.  As described in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784431/302243) answer, this can be done outside of your application by writing a wrapper script that does the backgrounding for you.

If this must be a general solution entirely in Python, then something like the following should do what you want:

```
cofo/__init__.py:

#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import wx

def main_app():
    app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
    frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
    app.MainLoop()

def gui_main():
    """Start GUI application.

    When running on Unix based platform, fork and detach so that terminal from
    which app may have been started becomes free for use.
    """
    if not hasattr(os, 'fork'):
        main_app()
    else:
        if os.fork() == 0:
            main_app()
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I have edited my question to explain it (hopefully) more clearly.

Comment: @Achim I've updated my answer.  I don't have access to OS X on which to test but this should do what you want.  Unfortunately it's not possible to have this completely generic across platforms, so the platfrom check is required.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the shell is waiting for the process to finish.  It seems you are looking for something similar to a daemon.  To do that, you can use `os.fork()` to create a copy of the process and then terminate the main process (parent) with `sys.exit()`.

```
if os.fork():
    # Finish the parent process    
    sys.exit()

# Your program starts here (child process)
```

Notice that this code has nothing to do with distutils.  It is your program which is going to behave as a daemon.